# Mathematica: FourierTransform of expression in a variable?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to understand why if I have an expression saved under a variable say sol, why I cannot do mathematical operations on it, as in:

```
DSolve[{m y''[x] + 2b y'[x] + c y[x] == 0}, y[x], x];
sol = %[[1, 1, 2]];
sol[x_] = sol;
FourierTransform[sol[x], x, w]
```

does not give me the fourier transform, but an error saying `x` is protected.
I tried putting sol directly inside FourierTransform, but that doesn't work either.

Is this an issue with lexical encoding? ie the variable `x` has to appear explicitly in the argument of `FourierTransform`?

Comment: There were just far too many typographic errors in this question. I get that you might not be a native speaker, and I understand how that could be (I would not want to have to ask and answer questions here in my own second language). But it helps to take the time to check your syntax and spelling carefully. The problem you are having could be a simple typo.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to see if it helps.

```
ClearAll[m, y, x, c, b, w]
sol = First@DSolve[{m y''[x] + 2 b y'[x] + c y[x] == 0}, y[x], x]
FourierTransform[y[x] /. sol, x, w]
```

gives

```
Sqrt[2*Pi]*C[2]*DiracDelta[(I*b - I*Sqrt[b^2 - c*m] + m*w)/m] + 
Sqrt[2*Pi]*C[1]*DiracDelta[(I*b + I*Sqrt[b^2 - c*m] + m*w)/m]
```

where `C[1]` and `C[2]` are the constant of integration.

Comment: thanks, i guess this as such: 
1. evaluate argument of FourierTransform
2. change  y[x] by rule sol
3. continue evaluation

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that your first line had a typo in it, which I've fixed.

The second problem is that you are trying to assign both a fixed definition and a function definition to the name `sol`.

Nasser's answer shows how to clean up the code, but does not explain why you were having problems with your version. The issue is the third line of your example, `sol[x_] = sol;`. The result `sol` is a replacement rule, as shown next:

```
{y[x] -> E^(((-b - Sqrt[b^2 - c*m])*x)/m)*C[1] + 
 E^(((-b + Sqrt[b^2 - c*m])*x)/m)*C[2]}
```

This doesn't make any sense in a function definition `sol[x_]:=...`, and in any case, having `sol` on both sides just confuses the issue.

Nasser's answer gives you what you need to get the desired output, but if you must have a function, the following will work.

```
sol = DSolve[{m y''[x] + 2 b y'[x] + c y[x] == 0}, y[x], x][[1]];
mysol[x_] := Evaluate[y[x] /. sol]
```

So for example:

```
mysol[2.] // InputForm
E^((2.*(-b - Sqrt[b^2 - c*m]))/m)*C[1] + 
 E^((2.*(-b + Sqrt[b^2 - c*m]))/m)*C[2]
```

Comment: Thanks! this works.  by the way, why do you need Evaluate in mysol definition, it seems to work without it. is it just to make sure the replacement occurs inside any functions that might have hold and call mysol?

Comment: It might well work without it (I didn't check extensively) but I put that in there because what you really want is the right-hand-side of the replacement rule (the bit after the `->`) not the `y[x]->` bit. There are certain circumstances where the `/.` is not sufficient and you need the `Evaluate` as well, e.g. inside a `Plot[]` function.

Comment: yes, i noticed that you need evaluate inside plot, as in using tables:
Plot[Evaluate@Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 3}], {x, 0, 15}]
do you know why you need it there? i am very curious! Thanks :)